# PhoneGap sqlLitePlugin DB.Transaction error Expected Token ')'

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I get strange Error from `db.transaction` if I'm trying to select some rows from table connection. I can't find any problem...

```
findAll: function (callback) {
    this.db.transaction(
        function (tx) {   
            var sql = 'SELECT * FROM connection;';
            tx.executeSql(sql, [], function (tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length, connections = [], i, connection;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    connection = new window.ConnectionModel();
                    connection.set(results.rows.item(i));
                    connections[i] = connection;
                }
                callback(connections);
            });
        },
        function (e) {
            console.log("Transaction Error: " + e.message);
        }
    );
}
```

Error: `Transaction Error: Expected token ')'`

Where should this token be? Where should I search?

Comment: You need to close the `this.db.transaction(` bracket.

Comment: but it is closed... I'll edit to show it.

Comment: Hmmm strange... I use WebSQL for local databases in Phonegap / Cordova. Maybe use this? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the `callback` function, not in the `db.transaction`. That's why I was getting an Error. 
So if somebody is getting curious errors in similar function, you should check you callback functions.